# AttributeError: module 'chess' has no attribute 'Board' chess board error

Tags: python, chess, python-chess

i'm making chess in python i'm having this error

this my code:

```
import chess.board

board=chess.Board()

board
```

full error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chess.py", line 1, in <module>
    import chess
  File "D:\Websites\repoting\chess.py", line 3, in <module>
    board=chess.Board()
AttributeError: module 'chess' has no attribute 'Board'
```

Comment: I don't have this module installed but the [docs](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) say that the proper syntax is `import chess` then `board = chess.Board()`

Comment: Is the file you've saved your code in named `chess.py` by any chance?  If so, do you get the same error if you change the name of this file?

Comment: if you post this answer i will select you post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `import chess` you can use `chess.Board()`. But if you `import chess.Board` you could only use `Board()`from module `chess`. I hope this will help you and everyone who will read this answer.